# MinGW C++ Linker - Why do i add gtest and not libgtest.a

Tags: linker, mingw

I followed [a guide on the internet](http://www.leifove.com/2013/01/how-to-set-up-eclipse-with-gcc-c.html) and everything works as described.

The step 10 in the guide confuses me though.

I previousely created an archive file of gtest and called it libgtest.a.
The guide explicitely tells me to enter gtest and not libgtest.a

I wonder why this would be true since at no other point i mention libgtest.a anywhere.
How does the MinGW C++ Linker know what file to use?
The directory contains other files that have gtest in their name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common GCC convention - when you pass `-lname` linker automatically search for `libname.a`. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html and `-l` option